# Symfony2: Set label of checkbox from Class Field

Tags: symfony, checkbox, formbuilder

I have a Class with 3 fields:

```
$id, $name, $isChecked
```

I have a formtype and I want, that the label of the $id field is the $name field. Is that possible?

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('id')
        ->add('name')
        ->add('is_checked', 'checkbox', array(
            'required' => false,
            'label' => //This should be the $name field
        ))
    ;
}
```

For example I have my Class with $id = 1, $name= "Car".
Then I want it like this:

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('id')
        ->add('name')
        ->add('is_checked', 'checkbox', array(
            'required' => false,
            'label' => 'Car',
        ))
    ;
}
```

--> The "Car" word should be the `$name` Variable of my Class. Or how do I make my whole Class as a Checkbox in my `Twig/Form`? I only want, that I can check my Checkbox and I than know, ok `"isChecked"` is true and then I have the relation to my ID and my Name. But the user needs to know, which checkbox is which value, so I need the "name" as the label

Comment: I'm a little confused by the first part, you said the label if the `id` field is the `name` field...do you mean the label of the `is_checked` field?  And do you want it to be the same as the label for `name`, or do you want it set to the current value of `name`?

Comment: Maybe you want something like that? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32458489/build-a-form-having-a-checkbox-for-each-entity

Comment: I edit my question, please have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is good documentation in Symfony on how to do this - what you want to do is [modify the form based on the underlying data](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#customizing-your-form-based-on-the-underlying-data).  What you'll do is add a form event on `PRE_SET_DATA`, which is used with the starting data.  Your `buildForm()` function would now look like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('id')
        ->add('name')
    ;

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $entity = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        // set default label if there is no data, otherwise use the name
        $label = (!$entity || null === $entity ->getId())
            ? 'Default'
            : $entity->getName()
        ;

        $form->add('is_checked', 'checkbox', array(
            'required' => false,
            'label' => $label,
        ));
    });
}
```

Another way would be to just pass the entity data to your template and manually set the label there, but the above solution is the more conventional way.